# Command line lint error after AndroidX migration

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, androidx

Seeing this lint error after migrating to AndroidX, only when running the build from the command line via `./gradle lintDebug`

I don't see any warnings or errors in Android Studio.

Here is the code that produces the error:

```
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

...

Snackbar.make(this.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content), R.string.recorder_permissions,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE") {
                // Request permission here
            }.show()
```

And the error:

```
app/src/debug/java/com/mobile/android/ui/LogInfoActivity.kt:214: Error: Must be one of: BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG or value must be ≥ 1 (was -2) [WrongConstant]
                      Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE"
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  app/src/debug/java/com/mobile/android/ui/LogInfoActivity.kt:258: Error: Must be one of: BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_LONG or value must be ≥ 1 (was -2) [WrongConstant]
                                  Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE"
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

build.gradle:
`implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01"`

The SnackBar.make method has an @IntDef requiring only the SnackBar.LENGTH...  constants.  Changing to the base class constants cause an error in Android Studio.

Build Tools version: 3.2.1
Gradle Version: 4.6

Answer (score 2):

Ended up being a stupid error.  One of our library projects had a gradle entry with an older version of the material dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1"
```

Changing it to this fixed it:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
```

Looks like it was a problem specific to the alpha1 release.  It can easily be recreated by creating a new Android project with a single activity.  Then convert the project to AndroidX.  This shows the error since it used the `alpha1` version after the conversion.  Creating the test project clued me on the error.